# INFO Bootstrapping environment : ERROR No matching node is available

Tags: juju, maas

Is there a logic that maas server could not work well with juju? 
After creating the node and adding to MaaS. We could see the node passing to the Ready status..BUT!!, juju bootstrap never works pretending something like:

```
 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: ppa type: maas)...
 ERROR No matching node is available.
```

No matching node is available??? what should juju knows to make this node available for it???? it s running, ready in maas and env file is well defined with MAAS keys...????

Answer (score 1):

Basically question still with no response beacuse of the error is not common when we plan to integrate juju and maas in a existing infrastructure. 
The answer could be one of the next propositions:

1. Wake-on-LAN for virtual machines does not work, MAAS supports "virsh".
2. Need to have nodes that are in the "ready" state before they can be allocated to a user.
3. Need to run and boot at least once, during which time they signal to the maas server that they are ready

Still one notice and will be nice if someboy had sure idea if juju bootstrap requires more than 2 nodes ???

Hopefully will help !!!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error for a while in a test deployment. What eventually resolved it for me was simply adding more nodes into MAAS. I ended up having 6-7 nodes in the 'Ready' state in MAAS and then juju was able to bootstrap correctly. Any fewer and it did not work, at least in my case.